# Selecting Injected Instance with Conditional

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have several classes that have inherited from one interface. I want the desired service to be loaded and used in the controller depending on the conditions.

Controller

```
public class GatewayController
{
    private readonly IAction action;

public GatewayController(IAction action)
{
    this.action = action;
}
[HttpPost("gateway")]
public async Task<ApiResult> Gateway(GatewayRequest gatewayRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var comId = gatewayRequest.CommandId;
        switch (comId)
        {
            case (int) GuaranteeItemStatus.End:
                return await action.Perform(gatewayRequest, cancellationToken); //must be use EndActionService

            case (int) GuaranteeItemStatus.SendProduct:
                return await action.Perform(gatewayRequest, cancellationToken);  //must be use SendProductActionService
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ApiResult.ToErrorModel("error");
    }

}
```

}

Parent interface:

```
 public interface IAction
    {
        Task<ApiResult> Perform(GatewayRequest gatewayRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
```

Services:

1-SendProductActionService:

```
 public class SendProductActionService:IAction
    {
        public async Task<ApiResult> Perform(GatewayRequest gatewayRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return ApiResult.ToSuccessModel("SendProduct");
        }
    }
```

2-EndActionService:

```
 public class EndActionService:IAction
    {
        public async Task<ApiResult> Perform(GatewayRequest gatewayRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return ApiResult.ToSuccessModel("EndAction");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Condition is based on the value sent by the client, so what you think about to create two endpoints (controller actions) one for `SendProduct` and another for `EndAction`?

Comment: This looks a lot like [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR/) :) You could use that instead, inject IMediator into the controller and send your query/command to it. It'll then route it to the correct handler for the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to register, and inject, an `IEnumerable` that contains all your `IAction`s.

First, to identify which `IAction` reacts to which command, you can add a `CommandId` property:

```cs
public interface IAction
{
    int CommandId { get; }
}

public class SendProductActionService : IAction
{
    public int CommandId => (int)GuaranteeItemStatus.SendProduct;
}

public class EndActionService : IAction
{
    public int CommandId => (int)GuaranteeItemStatus.End;
}
```

In your `Startup.cs`, you register all your actions:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IAction, SendProductActionService>();
services.AddScoped<IAction, EndActionService>();
```

Then in your controller, you inject all the `IAction`, and select the appropriate one when needed:

```cs
public class GatewayController
{
    // map the command ID to the proper IAction
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IAction> actions;

    // inject all the services registered that implement IAction
    public GatewayController(IEnumerable<IAction> actions)
    {
        this.actions = actions.ToDictionary(_ => _.CommandId);
    }
    
    [HttpPost("gateway")]
    public async Task<ApiResult> Gateway(GatewayRequest gatewayRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // find the appropriate IAction
        if (!actions.TryGetValue((int)gatewayRequest.CommandId, out var action)
            return BadRequest();
        
        return await action.Perform(gatewayRequest, cancellationToken);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<SendProductActionService>();
services.AddScoped<EndActionService>();
services.AddScoped<Func<GuaranteeItemStatus, IAction>>(serviceProvider => status =>
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case GuaranteeItemStatus.SendProduct:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<SendProductActionService>();
        case GuaranteeItemStatus.End:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<EndActionService>();
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
});
```

Your controller should be similar to this:

```
public class GatewayController
{
    private readonly Func<GuaranteeItemStatus, IAction> actionProvider;

    public GatewayController(Func<GuaranteeItemStatus, IAction> actionProvider)
    {
        this.actionProvider = actionProvider;
    }

    [HttpPost("gateway")]
    public async Task<ApiResult> Gateway(GatewayRequest gatewayRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await actionProvider((GuaranteeItemStatus)gatewayRequest.CommandId)
                .Perform(gatewayRequest, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ApiResult.ToErrorModel("error");
        }
    }
}
```